# Flutter textfield multiline with done ios

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm flutter dev trying to build a textfield with both multiline and done button. I've done it by adding done button manually on the AppBar but that is really ugly.

Today, i suddenly realized that there is something really cool in a native ios keyboard. It is even working now when i'm writing down multilines for this question.

[image]

As you can see, there are both return button on the bottom right corner, and also done button on top right corner. This is exactly what i want in my flutter ios app. I understand that android has a default keyboard control button on the bottom bar. But in ios, i really need this little done button up there.

Is there anyway to do this with flutter?? Not easy way? That's OK. Please let me know!! Hope this question reach gurus. Thanks in advance [:

Answer (score 2):

Yes I use [keyboard_actions](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions), it will help display the bar shown in the image, but not the return button.

Comment: too much overhead IMO

Comment: I would be happy to know if there was a simpler solution @Burak

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. What OP wants can be done easily in the native iOS. I think Flutter team has the figure it out how solve this problem. For know developers has to handle this in iOS (Android has a universal back button that can close the keyboard), wrapping the screen with `GestureDetector` and dismiss the keyboard when tap outside of the text field or use 3rd party packages like this.

Comment: As long as the desired behavior can be achieved using 3rd party libraries the flutter team will not implement it again, if they do so then we will not have such a wide variety of community supported libraries and will defeat the purpose of it.

Comment: You're right. Let's hope community comes up with a better  solution!

Comment: maybe we should detect keyboard visibility and attach custom positioned container which gon do the task 